# Error Transfer artifact : Connection Timeout

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

I'm trying to build a version of OpenTripPlanner on my system for the first time. There are a couple of dependencies errors, out of which I was able to resolve the first one by downloading the jar manually and adding it to the `.m2/repository`

However, I'm unable to get around the second dependency error. Following is the error log for the maven build

```
[INFO] opentripplanner-geocoder .......................... SUCCESS [  1.976 s]
[INFO] opentripplanner-gui ............................... FAILURE [ 11.088 s]
[INFO] opentripplanner-webapp ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 53.144 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-02-18T15:33:08-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/412M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project opentripplanner-gui: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.opentripplanner:opentripplanner-gui:jar:0.6.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.processing:core:jar:1.0.7: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.processing:core:jar:1.0.7: Could not transfer artifact org.processing:core:pom:1.0.7 from/to axis (http://people.apache.org/repo/m1-ibiblio-rsync-repository/org.apache.axis2/): connect timed out -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :opentripplanner-gui
```

I know it has something to do with `core-1.0.7.jar` but am unable to get around it

Comment: can you curl from your host to http://people.apache.org/repo/m1-ibiblio-rsync-repository/org.apache.axis2/ ?

Comment: yes, curl has no issues.

Comment: `org.processing:core:pom` is not available on that repository is it thirdparty or your local thing ?

Comment: It might've been the case that they would have removed it. The version I'm trying to build is a custom one, but based on an older version of OpenTripPlanner(http://www.opentripplanner.org/). I was wondering if I could download core-1.0.7.jar and add it manually, it might do the trick, not sure where to add it though

Comment: The problem seemed to be located here: ` Could not transfer artifact org.processing:core:pom:1.0.7 from/to axis (http://people.apache.org/repo/m1-ibiblio-rsync-repository/org.apache.axis2/): connect timed out -> [Help 1]` Your configuration in settings.xml looks wrong.

Comment: Do you mean the problem is in `pom.xml` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that switching the repository from OpenGeo to Conveyal was all that was required. Discussion thread which helped me to solve it : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/opentripplanner-users/pKPGut4iCyQ